# docker run multiline cmd in container from win cmd line; cmd or powershell not executed stays in multiline mode >>>

Tags: docker, docker-run

I'm trying to run a multiline curl cmd in a docker container and it always leaves the cmd in multiline mode.  I've tried using backtick in powershell and ^ windows command for line continuation with the same results

Powershell version

```
docker run --rm curlimages/curl:7.75.0 -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ""$env:DatabricksToken""" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' `
-d '{ `
 "path": "/Users/someone@mycompany.com/" `
 }' https://https://...azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/workspace/list
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that powershell automatically continues a line if there is an open quote.  When I removed the back tick from the 2nd and 3rd line it worked.